# What is the point of the Symmetric type in Julia?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

What is the point of the `Symmetric` type in the `LinearAlgebra` package of Julia? It seems like it is equivalent to the type `Hermitian` for real matrices (although: is this true?). If that is true, then the only case for which `Symmetric` is not redundant with `Hermitian` is for complex matrices, and it would be surprising to want to have a symmetric as opposed to Hermitian complex matrix (maybe I am mistaken on that though).

I ask this question in part because I sometimes find myself doing casework like this: if I have a real matrix, then use `Symmetric`; if complex, then `Hermitian`. It seems though that I could save work by just always using `Hermitian`. Will I be missing out on performance or otherwise if I do this?

(Also, bonus question that may be related: why is there no `HermTridiagonal` type in addition to `SymTridiagonal`? I could use the former. Plus, it seems more useful than `SymTridiagonal` in consideration of the above.)

Comment: Given that this is a bit of an open-ended question it might be better asked at https://discourse.julialang.org/

Comment: At the suggestion of @SimonByrne I did cross-post the question at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/what-is-the-point-of-the-symmetric-type/40773/2 which has helpful discussion.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the answer from the linked discourse thread (via @stevengj):

> Always use Hermitian. For real elements, there is no penalty compared to Symmetric.
>
> There aren’t any specialized routines for complex Symmetric matrices that I know of. My feeling is that it was probably a mistake to have a separate Symmetric type in LinearAlgebra, but it is hard to remove at this point.

Comment: The right answer would probably be to alias `Symmetric` to `Hermitian{<:Real}`